# How worried should I be about my dog having her second wart in a year or so?

Tags: dogs, skin-condition, infections

Last year, my dog (a female yellow lab, who is now about 2 1/2 years old) developed a growth on her leg.  I took her to the vet, and the diagnosis was a relief - it was just a wart (I don't remember the actual term the vet used, but it boiled down to "warts").  He told me to expect more of the same, sooner or later, but she just got another one, in more or less the same place (I don't remember which leg the first one was on, but it was near the knee, and that's where the new one is).

**I'm going to take her back to the vet to make sure it's nothing serious, of course**, but I was wondering how worried I should be until I actually get her into the vet's office.  If the vet said "There will almost certainly be more to follow", and the growth is very similar to the first one, it is almost definitely just another wart, right?

Comment: Very probably. I wouldn't worry about it, but I would still get it checked out.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about it. My dogs have gotten warts as they age. It's completely normal. (My Silky has about 6 now on various spots. My Yorkie had about 12.) The only time you should be concerned is if it acts like a growth on a human: quickly grows, etc.